# Blazor Update Component in LoginDisplay

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a component in the LoginDisplay.razor file which displays a number from a "numberservice" as follows:

```
<span class="main-nav-text">@NumberService.Number</span>
```

This number gets updated using the OnInitializedAsync method:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authstate = await GetAuthenticationStateAsync.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        try
        {
            NumberService.Update(authstate.User);
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Here is the Service:

```
public class NumberService
    {
        private UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        public NumberService(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public void Update(ClaimsPrincipal User)
        {
            var UserIdClaim = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            Number++;
        }
    }
```

What I need to do is then update this number through a different razor page and get the LoginDisplay to update. I can call the UpdateNumber function in the razor form fine but I don't know how to get the LoginDisplay to update. If I refresh the page it updates with the new number but I'd like to do it once the button is clicked on the other razor page:

```
private async Task UpdateNumber()
    {
        var authstate = await GetAuthenticationStateAsync.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        NumberService.Update(authstate.User);
    }
```

I feel like I'm quite close and I just need to have something in the LoginDisplay that checks to see if the int has updated in the service but I cannot see what so any help would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

for anyone who wants to know how to resolve this, I ended up using a thread inside as follows:

```
var authstate = await GetAuthenticationStateAsync.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    CHeckNumberChange = new System.Threading.Timer(async (object? stateInfo) =>
    {
        try
        {
            NumberService.Update(authstate.User);
        }
        catch { }
        await InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
    }, new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false), 2000, 2000);
```

It might not be the nicest of solutions but hey it works.